# WPF Datagrid not show Text

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpfdatagrid

pressing the tab in writing datagrid cell then Does not showed up text..
How to Solve ??

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_name"   Width="*" Header="Item Name" />
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_unit"   Width="*" Header="Unit"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_qty"   Width="*" Header="Qnty"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_rate"   Width="*" Header="Unit Rate"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="total_rate"   Width="*" Header="Total Rate"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_cgst"   Width="*"  Header="CGST(%)"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_sgst"   Width="*" Header="SGST(%)"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="total_amount"   Width="*" Header="Total Amount"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Did you set the itemssource prop ? and also post the entire data grid and Vm if u are using mvvm.

Comment: yes .itemsource used

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using Binding prop so it's not displaying on UI here is the code Which I tested and working fine

```
  <DataGrid Name="item_list">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_name" Binding="{Binding itemname}"  Width="*" Header="Item Name" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_unit" Binding="{Binding itemitemunit}"  Width="*" Header="Unit"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_qty" Binding="{Binding itemqty}"  Width="*" Header="Qnty"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_rate" Binding="{Binding itemrate}"   Width="*" Header="Unit Rate"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="total_rate"   Width="*" Header="Total Rate"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_cgst"   Width="*"  Header="CGST(%)"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="item_sgst"   Width="*" Header="SGST(%)"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="total_amount"   Width="*" Header="Total Amount"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>




  private void add_sale_Loaded()
        {

            collection.Add(new Proxy { itemitemunit = "1", itemname = "1", itemqty = "1", itemrate = "1" });
            item_list.CanUserAddRows = false;
            item_list.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            item_list.ItemsSource = collection;
        }

//Global
 ObservableCollection<Proxy> collection { get; set; }
//CTOR
 collection = new ObservableCollection<Proxy>();
            item_list.ItemsSource = collection;
            add_sale_Loaded();
            add_sale_Loaded();
```

Comment: Np also note  `item_list.CanUserAddRows = false;` for last empty row
           ` item_list.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` not displaying proxy class props